# How do I notify a JSP when an object's state changes?

Tags: java, jsp, polling

I need to create a *User Monitor* screen that shows real-time data of the logged-in users. I was told that I should use a particular Java class (let's call it Aggregator.java) that was created by somebody that aggregates all the necessary information that needs to be displayed. Aggregator.java polls from the database every 5 seconds and stores all the data in a cache. Once it updates the cache, Aggregator.java notifies all the dependents that implement a particular interface.

In this case, how can my JSP be notified about the changes in Aggregator.java? Initially, I planned to use WebSockets but since I have to use this Aggregator.java, I'm not sure about what to do.

If there's even a dirty way on how to do this, I would love to know about it. But, of course, I'm all about them best practices.

Comment: Because I have to use Aggregator.java. It has to be that way. Aggregator.java notifies all its dependents if the cache is updated. 

@brso05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Spring Integration with a WebSocket outbound adapter.

You can create a channel and send a message with the updates from your Aggregator.java